# Ignore divs surrounding grid cells in display: grid

Tags: html, css

I have a grid-layout with 3 children, each spanning 4 out of 12 columns, to create a horisontal 3 column layout. A simplified example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/bnyy6fde/1/.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <h3>Grid element 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <h3>Grid element 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <h3>Grid element 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CMS wraps each child in a div, which causes the grid layout to render incorrectly. This can be seen here, demonstrated by the div with class 'not-working': https://jsfiddle.net/e6b2yf37/2/.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Depending on the editor's setup, the number of columns can span from 1 to 4 elements per row. As such, it is not possible to simply solve this, by giving the div, 'not-working', grid-column-end: 4.

It is not possible to remove the divs wrapping each child in the CMS.

Is there a pure CSS-solution, which simply ignores the div 'not-working' regardless of the number of columns the children span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.grid {display: flex;}
.not-working {flex-grow: 1; width: 10%;}
```

Your divs should now fill the grid equally.

Comment: Hello Carele,
Thank you for your suggestion. It works for the scenario, but I realized I forgot to add `flex-flow: row wrap;` to the wrapper, which makes `display: flex` render incorrectly. I have updated the question to reflect this change.

Comment: @AndreasChristiansen Try to add  flex-grow: 1; to your divs !

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in the Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/e6b2yf37/3/

Comment: Then you may add "width: 10%" to your divs. It will work up to 10 divs/row. The original size will be 10% and flex grow will tell them to grow as much as they can, without going over the max size of the screen or stacking on top of each other. It works on your fiddle.

Comment: No problem. It was hard to get right because it is a pretty hacky way to do it. However i would favour this over any js/jquery workaround for efficiency.

Answer (score 10):

Well actually... All you needed was `display: contents`.

You only need to add this in your CSS:

```
.not-working {
  display: contents;
}
```

See also: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bc1nq30g/).

Note that it only works well in Firefox, so you might want to test it in various browsers before you use this. There might be some accessibility issues with your content. See also: [Can I Use notes](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents).

Comment: Gold star to you Sir

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a flex layout, but then you would lose the look of elements aligned in a grid when there is wrapping.

You can use `auto-fit` and simply forget about the possibility of 12 columns. It will show 12 columns if there is room and wrap if necessary while maintaining the grid look.

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 24px;
    grid-gap: var(--mdc-layout-grid-gutter-desktop, 24px);
    margin: 0;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 1</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 2</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 3</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 4</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 5</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="not-working">
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <h3>Grid element 6</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about just changing the styline to .not-working i.e.

```
.not-working {
    width: auto;
    grid-column-end: span 4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, omukiguy, but the solution only works for exactly 3 elements per row, and does not scale for 4 or more elements.

Comment: @andreas-christiansen unless I don't get you question well. Check out https://codepen.io/bahiirwa/pen/breQav

Comment: Your solution works for 3 elements per row, but cannot display 4 elements or more per row.
I was looking for a general solution where the CSS could remain unchanged on the not-working element, and have the number of elements per row defined by it's child (the grid cell).

Comment: This is a hack. 

You could swap out classes with Jquery/JS. Then eliminate the grid-cell class in your original HTML.

`$("#gridID").attr('not-working', 'grid-cell'); `  or 

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.not-working').removeClass('not-working').addClass('grid-cell');
});`